# Firebase hosting redirect to shebang

Tags: firebase, redirect, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I have an SPA hosted on firebase, that uses hash routing (e.g. routes/urls are mysite.com/#!/mypath).

I'm trying to configure firebase hosting to redirect requests from "mysite.com/mypath" to "mysite.com/#!/mypath" but am having no luck. I've tried:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/:path*",
    "destination": "/index.html/#!/:path"
  }
]
```

and:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html/#!/"
  }
]
```

and also:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
],
"redirects": [
  {
    "source": "/:path*",
    "destination": "/#!/:path",
    "type": 301
  }
]
```

Is this possible to do? Paths can also be like "mysite.com/mypath1/part2", etc.

Comment: Having the same problem, have you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting redirect captures cannot currently be applied to query parameters or hashes. If this is something you'd like to see, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features)!